# What are the dicrepencies ?Can anyone assist?

Tags: maven

I have JDK 17 and Maven 3.8.1 still getting errors for maven build

[image: 1]

I am using the command "mvn clear install -DskipTests"

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Did you try what it suggested: "mvn clean install -X -rf :camel-webservice"?